# How can you determine if textboxes inside a table row are empty using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
 var emptyFields = false;

 function checkNotEmpty(tblName, columns, className){

    emptyFields = false;

     $("."+className+"").each(function() {
          if($.trim($(this).val()) === "" &amp;&amp; $(this).is(":visible")){
             emptyFields = true;
             return false; // break out of the each-loop
          }
     });

      if (emptyFields) {
             alert("Please fill in current row before adding a new one.")
       } else {
              AddRow_OnButtonClick(tblName,columns);
       }
}
```

Its checking that all elements in the table are not empty before adding a new row, and **I only need to check that the last row of the table has at least an element which its not empty and not the whole table**.

The className its applied to the table. Please notice, that the problem I have its checking the last row and only one element of the row has to have some text in it. (e.g. each row has 5 textboxes at least one textbox need to have some text inside in order to be able to add another row, otherwise, the alert comes up).

Comment: Could you consider posting your HTML snippet defining at least the table and one table row?  That would help a lot.

Comment: I am revising the code, If I can't find what is wrong I will post it.
Thanks to all of you, I would give you lots of votes to all of you if I could. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
if ($('.' + className + ' tr:last input:text:visible[value]').length > 0) {
    AddRow_OnButtonClick(tblName,columns);
} 
else {
    alert("Please fill in current row before adding a new one.")
}
```

This of course assumes the `className` you're using is used on the `table` element.

#### Working example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        if ($('.test tr:last input:text:visible[value]').length > 0) {
            alert('SUCCESS - at least 1 value is filled in!');
        } 
        else {
            alert("FAIL - all textboxes on last row are empty.")
        }
    });
});
</script>

<table class="test" border="1">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="filled" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="in" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click Me!" />
```

Comment: @John Rasch:Thanks! I really hoped this works, but even if all fields are filled in in the last row, the alert comes up. Also, it only checks for text boxes, Would I have to make an else if statement to check for other elements shuch textareas, selectboxes?Thanks a lot.

Comment: @John Rasch: Darm! I does the same with the className, I can not create a new row, the alert comes up even if all fields have data in it. Thanks a lot for trying.

Comment: @Cesar - this definitely works for a test example I've written, which I will include shortly.

Comment: @John Rasch: You are right, this works, I am looking what could it be wrong on my code. I can see that you only look for input:text, how could I capture any element (e.g. textboxes, textareas, selectboxes, and others shuch radio and check boxes if possible)? Thanks.

Comment: @Cesar - that's a little bit more complicated, but I believe you can do that using the selector `'.test tr:last :input[value]:not(:checkbox):not(:radio),.test tr:last :input[value]:checked'`

Comment: Thanks, for all your help, you were all right with the code, I did have a mistake on the coding, but I fixed now, and your solutions its the best. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector and some children in addition to `"."+classname`?  Something along the lines of `$("."+classname+" tr:last td")` should check each cell in the last row.

EDIT:
Initially suggested `last-child`, but switching to something that fits the OP's needs better on comment.

Comment: To check the last row I added the following:$("."+className+":last").each(function() and work. I now only need to check that any of the elements has text and not all elements on the last row, thanks.

Comment: @Cesar Lopez - How about setting a variable outside of the closure that you set to true if one's .text() is non-empty and non-null?

Comment: @just: Sorry I did not solve getting to check the last tr, I was checking the last td instead. I also tried the solution :last-child td but it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @Cesar Lopez - try `$("."+className+"tr:last td").each(...)`

Comment: @Justkt: I tried that but it does not work either, I dont know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Cesar Lopez - consider merging my solution (the selector I have) with karim's.  Try `$("."+className+"tr:last td:visible[value]").length`

Comment: @Justkt: :-(, did not work either, I really dont know what I am doing wrong. :-(. Thanks a lot anyway for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a loop:

```
if($("." + className + ":visible[value]").length) {
   // one or more has been filled out, and is visible
   // [value] matches non-empty values only
}
```

Comment: @karim79:I tried your if statement but it does not seem to work, also when you say one or more values has been filled out, how do I check this? Thanks.

Comment: @Cesar Lopez - That if statement returns the number of visible elements that have a non-empty value, so if it evaluates to true, then add another row, otherwise `alert('Please fill in...`

Comment: That would check all elements on the table, I think, I need to check only the elements from the last row of the table, would that be possible? Thanks a lot.